# Why are my keypad pins more than total number of columns and rows?

Tags: microcontroller, keypad

I have newly bought the following keypad with 4 rows and 3 columns from a not well-recognized shop. But I am wondering, why it has 10 pins in spite of 7 pins (total number of rows and columns). Consequently, I am confused how to implement this keypad.
[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for your keypad. They are not all the same.

Comment: I couldn't find any datasheet, but if needed, I can send you a picture

Comment: Yes, show us a picture. Where did you buy it from?

Comment: there may e some variations of that keypad with a backlight or with indicator LEDs, the extra pins are probably to support those options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [this 3x4 keypad](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14662):

[image]

and its [pinout datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/7/e/f/6/f/sparkfun_keypad.pdf):

[image]

It has 9 pins, but only 7 are used. The outer two go nowhere in particular and are probably just solder-down points to increase strength and/or to allow you not to connect up all the main pins while still having strong support for tying the board more solidly.

Now imagine that the underlying board of your unit was designed to handle both 3x4 ***and*** 4x4 keyboard tops, while using the same underlying board with the outer two still having the same tie-down purpose. There'd be 10 pins. But still, only the inner 8 would matter in that case.

It's very easy for you to test your board to find out which lines are important. Ignore the outer two, for now. Just focus on the remaining eight and use your ohmmeter between any two pins and press each key in succession. If any of them connect, the ohmmeter will show it. If none of the keys do that, then you know than one or the other of the two pins you picked is "useless." From there, you can work forward and eventually figure out which 7 pins are valid and which 3 aren't (the outer two and one of the inner 8.) Now you have your 7 pins worked out and you can move forward from there.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you so much.